# Requesting a Tag for the mobile game 'Mafia City'

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I have a few questions about the *mobile game* **Mafia City**, but when I try asking a question, I cannot use the tag `mafia-city` because that tag does not exist. I cannot create a new tag either because I am new and I do not have enough reputation. Therefore I am kindly requesting anyone who has 300 reputation at least to create this tag.

Comment: Hi Sandun - welcome to the site! If you ask your question and tag it with [tag:android] or [tag:ios] I'll retag it for you. Once the tag exists, you'll be able to ask subsequent questions using the tag with no issue

Comment: @Robotnik Thank you. I followed your advice and asked a question with the android tag. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/377958/mafia-city-mobile-how-do-i-build-on-an-occupied-land

Comment: no problem, glad to help! I've now edited your post with the [tag:mafia-city] tag :)